# Animations for ipad/iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I am trying to make an app for ipad/iphone with a lot of animations.
There is anyway to make an app in objective-c with animations in other languages and interligate them???
because i have  a lot of skills in languages like after effects/illustrator/flash/etc, for that, will be better to me to make the animations in that technologies..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can export your animations into an HTML5 format, you can certainly display them in a UIWebView. There are a few Flash-to-HTML5 projects available out there now, and new apps like Hype and Purple that can be used to create HTML5 animations "from scratch."

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do this is to create the videos in whatever tools and then export to a series of PNG images or use ffmpeg to convert flash or whatever to a series of images. Then display these PNG images one at a time (and don't load them all or you will use up all app memory). If you can deal with a more lossy format, then h.264 can save a lot of space at the cost of a significantly reduced 4:2:0 YUV type colorspace. If you need lossless video or require an alpha channel, or you want to save a lot of space as compared to the PNG method then you should take a look at AVAnimator. Note that you should not integrate any ffmpeg related code into your iOS due to license issues having to do with static linking of LGPL code.